# Prevent Mp3 file to play in another Media player

Tags: android, mp3, media-player, encryption

I am developing media player and my application download mp3 file from server .

So i want to prevent it from another media player to play it.

### Case

User get file from server (music file1.mp3) in android phone ! User play it in our player but can't share it or download it in computer or play in another media player.

### I try Below

I can encrypt a file and decrypt it again in my app (will take long time, it's a mobile cpu!), but then my application needs to have the decryption key inside. Basically anyone can read this key from my app so its not the good solution.

So please suggest me what i have to do ?

Thanks..

Comment: Unfortunately, I think encryption is the only way to go. Try to use a very weak and fast encryption. If someone wants to crack the encryption and get to the mp3 files they will eventually, it's just a matter of time. Have a look at the music service Spotify, they stream all their music and allows users to safe music files on their computer or phone. They use a full file encryption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So please suggest me what i have to do ?

Write some other app.

What you are describing is [DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management). There is no known DRM system that is unbreakable. There are DRM systems that have been broken, and there are DRM systems that nobody has bothered trying to break yet.